# Need to extract data matching child model and also the parent data linked to it

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I am new to  world of Django and Python. I have two models: Testing (Parent) & Heat_Status (Child):

Models:

```
class Testing(models.Model):
Testing_Date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
IE_Testing = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s   %s' %(self.Testing_Date, self.Testing_Shift)

class Heat_Status(models.Model):
Heat_Number=models.CharField(max_length=6)
Testing_Detail=models.ForeignKey(Testing,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s   %s' %(self.Heat_Number, self.Testing_Detail.Testing_Result)
```

Now I want to search a Heat_Number saved in database along with the details linked to its Parent in Testing model. I got a way to search the data but unable to access the foreign key. I am posting my code here.

Views:

```
    def status (request):
    if request.method=="POST":
    srch=request.POST['srh']

    if srch:
        match= Heat_Status.objects.filter(Q(Heat_Number__iexact=srch))


        if match:
            return render (request,'status.html',{'sr':match})
        else:
            messages.error(request,'NO Heat')
    else:
        return reverse('status')
    return render(request,'status.html')
```

Template

```
        <form method="POST" action="/crinsp/status">
            {%csrf_token%}
            input type="text" name="srh" classs="form-control">
            <button class="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Search</button>
         </form>
        {%if sr %}
        {%for k in sr%}
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Heat Number</td>
            <td>{{k.Heat_Number}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rolled in</td>
            <td> {{**k.Heat_Status.Testing.Testing_Date**}} </td> # I need Help here
        </tr>
        </table>
        {%endfor%}
        {%endif%}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct and answer for the problem is just a slight change in the HTML code.

While calling the information of parent field we must use the name assigned to foreign key in child model.

```
      {{ k. Testing_Detail. Testing_Date}}
```